# How Do I Make a Program to Calculate The Value Of Each Word

Tags: python, debugging

I'm trying to make a program calculate the value of each word if a is 1, b is 2, c is 3, and so on. I've made most of the code, but it doesn't work. Could anyone give me some suggestions? I've only recently started learning python, so could you be as detailed as possible? Thanks.

```
output = ('None')
worth = {'a':1,
'b':2,
'c':3,
'd':4,
'e':5,
'f':6,
'g':7,
'h':8,
'i':9,
'j':10,
'k':11,
'l':12,
'm':13,
'n':14,
'o':16,
'q':17,
'r':18,
's':19,
't':20,
'u':21,
'v':22,
'w':23,
'x':24,
'y':25,
'z':26,
}


def findworth():
    for char in wordlist:
        if char in wordlist:
           output = (worth[char])
           wordlist.replace(output) 
        elif worth[char] == False:
            output = (None)
        
while True:
    output = (None)
    wordlist = []
    word = input(str("Find out how many cents your word is worth. Please enter your word:"))
    word = word.lower()
    wordlist = list(word)
    wordlist = findworth()
    output = sum(wordlist)
    print("Your word's value is:")
    print (output)
    print('.')
```

This is what is shows when I run it:

```
**Find out how many cents your word is worth. Please enter your word:Bananas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/User/School/__CentsWord/WordWorth.py", line 49, in <module>
    wordlist = findworth()
  File "C:/User/School/__CentsWord/WordWorth.py", line 39, in findworth
    wordlist.replace(output)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'**
```

Comment: I know that. I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: A python `list` doesn't have a `replace` function, it's also a risky practise to modify a list whilst you're iterating through it. This can cause all sorts of problems. Also, your main loop expects your `findworth` function to return a list of numbers, which it currently does not do. So you could, at the start of the `findworth` function, define an empty list and then append the worth of each character as you iterate through the list.

Comment: Just for fun, try `print(sum(ord(c) - 96 for c in "hello"))`. Works for lowercase a-z only though.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that avoids more advanced techniques:

```
worth = {
    'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6, 'g':7,
    'h':8, 'i':9, 'j':10, 'k':11, 'l':12, 'm':13, 'n':14,
    'o':15, 'q':17, 'r':18, 's':19, 't':20, 'u':21, 
    'v':22, 'w':23, 'x':24, 'y':25, 'z':26}

def findworth(word):
    total = 0
    for char in word:
        if char in worth:
            total += worth[char]
    return total

print("Find out how many cents your word is worth.")

while True:
    word = input("Please enter your word: ").lower()
    print("Your word's value is:", findworth(word))
```

Giving you output as follows:

```
Find out how many cents your word is worth.
Please enter your word: abc
Your word's value is: 6
Please enter your word: hello
Your word's value is: 53
```

---

**Note:** `worth` is currently missing `p`, giving `o` an incorrect value, it should probably be:

```
worth = {
    'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6, 'g':7,
    'h':8, 'i':9, 'j':10, 'k':11, 'l':12, 'm':13, 'n':14,
    'o':15, 'p':16, 'q':17, 'r':18, 's':19, 't':20, 'u':21, 
    'v':22, 'w':23, 'x':24, 'y':25, 'z':26}
```

Comment: Normally yes, but the OP gives `o` as `16` not `15`.

Answer (score 1):

My first comment would be that the method used to generate `worth` is quite long winded and so prone to mistakes, in fact, it appears that you've forgotten `'p'` and instead used `'o':16`. You can instead generate your list of worths using a dictionary comprehension:

```
worth = {chr(x+96):x for x in range(1,27)}
```

This works by looping over the numbers 1..26, and converting `n + 96` to a character (Use an ASCII table to see that 97 is `'a'`, 98 is `'b'` and so on, this character is then used as the key to the value.

Next we can generate a list of the values for each character in the word:

```
word = "hello"
scores = [worth[c] for c in word]
```

This will gives us `scores == [8, 5, 12, 12, 5]`.

Lastly, you can call the `sum` function to add up all of the values in a list:

```
sum(scores)
```

which returns `52`.

You can put this together into a function to get:

```
def get_word_score(word):
    worth = {chr(x+96):x for x in range(1,27)}
    scores = [worth[c] for c in word]
    return sum(scores)
```

Alternatively this can be done on 1 line with:

```
sum([ord(c)-96 for c in word])
```

`ord` does the opposite of `chr`, it returns the ASCII value of the character given.

As a walkthrough of `sum([ord(c)-96 for c in word])` using the word `'hello'`. The first step is to get each character into a list:

```
>>> [c for c in 'hello']
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Next convert each character to its ASCII value:

```
>>> [ord(c) for c in 'hello']
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Next convert each ASCII value to the alphabet position by subtracting 96:

```
>>> [ord(c)-96 for c in 'hello']
[8, 5, 12, 12, 15]
```

And finally sum:

```
>>> sum([ord(c)-96 for c in 'hello'])
52
```

Your code function then be:

```
while True:
    word = input("Find out how many cents your word is worth. Please enter your word:").lower()
    output = sum([ord(c)-96 for c in word])
    print("Your word's value is:", output, ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your solution (it is not very good imo, will provide a better one)

```
def findworth():
    for i,char in enumerate(wordlist):
        if char in worth:
            output = (worth[char])
            wordlist[i] = (output) 
        else:
            output = (None)

while True:
    output = (None)
    wordlist = []
    word = input(str("Find out how many cents your word is worth. Please enter your word:"))
    word = word.lower()
    wordlist = list(word)
    findworth()
    output = sum(wordlist)
    print("Your word's value is:")
    print (output)
    print('.')
```

A better solution by reducing redundancies

```
while True:
    word = input(str("Find out how many cents your word is worth. Please enter your word:"))
    word = word.lower()
    output = 0 # set initial value
    for char in word: # iterate string for each character
        if char in worth: # check if its a valid char
            output += worth[char] # same as output = output + worth[char]

    print("Your word's value is:")
    print (output)
    print('.')
```

Python's string is already iterable, so you do not have to make it into a list :)

Comment: `output = sum(worth[char] for char in word.lower() if char in worth)`, `sum()` a comprehension to reduce the `for` loop to one line, saves enough space to add a Stopping Condition: `if not output:
        break`